# Haskell - Different log methods

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and was playing around with some number manipulation in different bases when I had to write an integer logarithm function for my task.

I don't mean discrete/modular logs, but simply `greatest x s/t b^x <= n`

I developed a few versions and can't decide which I like best.  Was hoping to hear what some of you think, or if you have other alternatives to suggest

All have signature: `intlog :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a`

```
intlog :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
intlog n b
    | n < b = 0
    | otherwise = succ (intlog (div n b) b)

intlog' :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
intlog' n b = maximum [i | i<-[0..n], b^i <= n]

logg = log . fromIntegral
intlog'' :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
intlog'' intlog n b = floor $ logg n / logg b
```

The 'best' one relies on haskell's standard natural log function which I was hoping to avoid (as an exercise) and somewhat messy type conversion.  Of the remaining two, one is probably fastest but seems nearly procedural in nature.  The other feels very functional and 'haskelly' (looking for word analogous to pythonic, meaning in haskells best style) but i cant see it being too efficient unless there is really really good optimization under the hood.

Would love to hear what you guys think.

BTW - i know that for the second one, `intlog'` i could find a better upperbound than `n` but im looking for feedback and/or different way to code it.  not incremental improvement like that

Comment: I don't really know haskell, and so can't say which one is best, but `intlog''` is clearly the worst, as it will produce the wrong output! `log` returns floating point values, which aren't always exact - for example `3^5 == 243`, but `logg 243 / logg 3 == 4.999999999999999`, so `floor $ logg 243 / logg 3 == 4`, instead of the correct `5`. (And yes, `logBase 3 243` has the same problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your `intLog'` function is definitely that it goes through all `n` numbers in the list. As a result of this it takes ages for large `n` (for `n = 2^130` it ran until I killed it, while your other solutions all returned the result instantly).

The reason that it has to go through all the numbers is of course that using a condition in a list comprehension is like using `filter` and does not make use of the fact that once the condition is false for the first time, it will always be false thereafter. What you should use instead is `takeWhile` which takes elements from the list while the condition is true and then stops the first time the condition is false. This way the code would look like this:

```
intlog n b = maximum $ takeWhile (\i -> b^i <= n) [0..]
```

Since it will no longer go through the list to its end, we also no longer need to pick an upper bound and can just leave it off. This function will instantly return a result like the other solutions.

---

Of course, except for learning purposes, the best solution is still to just use the built-in functionality with conversion as there is no point reinventing the wheel. Regarding that you should note that you can use the prelude function `logBase` instead of dividing the `log`s of `n` and `b`.

Comment: hah i didnt even know about logBase.  but thanks for suggesting the `takeWhile` that is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for.  i liked that solution the best due to its conciseness except for the obvious efficiency problem.

Comment: also noticed `logBase` has arguments with other order, which makes sense since the base is the argument you'd more likely want to curry.  i need to get in the habit of thinking like that when specifying argument order

Comment: You are right that in most cases one should use the built-in functionality, but we're talking about an integer version of a floating-point function here; Using the built-in `log` or `logBase` with conversion in this case will give incorrect results! `log` and `logBase` both return floating point values, which aren't always exact - for example `3^5 == 243`, but `logg 243 / logg 3 == 4.999999999999999`, so `floor $ logg 243 / logg 3 == 4`, instead of the correct `5`. (And `logBase 3 243` gives the same result, too)